# order tracking remainder

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have the following Mysql Table

```
Order table 
status 0 - incomplete
status 1 - complete  

PO_invoice| Company| transactionType| Amt_Paid | Balance | Status| dateCreated|
 1001     | Astek  |               3|     10000|    10000|    0  |2012-10-15  |
 1002     | Asrack |               2|     20000|        0|    1  |2012-10-20  |
```

**Transaction table**

It contains the explanation of the mode of payment

- if type 1 then the full amount should be paid on the same day
- if type 2 then the 50% on same day and after
- 30 days other 50% amount should be paid
- if type 3 then the 60% on same day and after
- 60 days other 60% amount should be paid

  ```
  transactionType | noDays | PercentSplit  |

                 1|      0 |            0  |
                 2|     30 |            50 |
                 3|     60 |            60 |
  ```

I am trying to track the orders which are due for payment

currently i am joining the two tables on transaction type and status 0

```
$query = "select Order.PO_invoice, Order.Company, Order.Amt_Paid, Order.Balance,
          Order.dateCreated, Transaction.noDays,Transaction.PercentSplit 
          INNER JOIN Transaction
          ON Order.transactionType = Transaction.transactionType AND
           Order.status =0"
```

and looping in PHP, and checking if the

```
currentTime - Order.dateCreated  > = Transaction.noDays
```

if it is then display the row else skip the row.

I want to know whether there is a way to do this in MYSQL only and return only those rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried -

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),Order.dateCreated) >= Transaction.noDays
```

Comment: +1, this would work but will i be able to order by that value so that , the max elaped time would be displayed first.

Comment: have you tried using the same in order by, like, `order by DATEDIFF(NOW(),Order.dateCreated)`

Comment: or you can use `DATEDIFF(NOW(),Order.dateCreated)` as one of the column, give it a alias, and then use the alias in `order by`